how to store file name in database from file input tag in laravel
I'm trying to store filename that is actually stored in the folder in my database. I'm saving files as their original names. Everything works properly except that when I try to store the names in database, some temporary file names are stored instead of intended names.
public function store(taskRequestStore $request,TaskService $service)
    {
        
        $destination= base_path().'/public/TaskFiles/'.date('Y').'/'.date('m');
        if(!is_dir($destination))
        {
            mkdir($destination,0777,true);
        }
         $destination=$destination.'/';
         $filename=rand(1111111,99999999);
         $file=$request->file('TaskFile');
         $newfilename=$filename.$request->file('TaskFile')->getClientOriginalName();
         $file->move($destination,$newfilename);
         $path=$request->file('TaskFile')->getClientOriginalName();
         $request->TaskFile=$newfilename;
 
         $attributes = $request->all(['Caption','office_id','Type','TaskFile'
                                    'Commander_id','OtherOffices'
                                    ]);
                    
        $office = $service->create($attributes);
        return redirect()->back()->with(['create'=>'recored inserted']);
    }

I want to store the filename in the database with the same name that I transferred to the TaskFile folder.

finally resolve it by adding this line after request->all():
$attributes['TaskFile']=$newfilename;

